# VB.net Time Zone Issues

Tags: vb.net, timezone

I have a legacy application that uses the windows time zone information for calculating dates.  For example, 35 = East Coast, 20 = central, 15=mountain.  Here is the current function.  It takes a date with a timezone and converts it to the timezone passed in.  This works just fine on xp, but it crashes on Windows 7.  I am guessing it has to do with the win32 portion of it or Windows 7 handles time zones differently.

I would prefer not to change the format of the time zone as that could cause some issues.  The code is vb.net and I did not write it.

```
Public Shared Function ConvertTime(ByVal time As Date, ByVal timeZone As Integer) As Date
        Dim UtcNow As Date = time.ToUniversalTime

        Dim selectedTimeZone As TimeZones.Win32.Win32TimeZone = TimeZones.Win32.TimeZones.GetTimeZone(timeZone)

        Return selectedTimeZone.ToLocalTime(UtcNow)
    End Function
```

Anyone have this issue before?

Comment: The reason it does not work for anything after Windows XP is getting the TimeZone requires elevated privliages.  This is simple enough to do within th ecode.  Of course you don't need to use the Win32 function to determine the system time and timezone.  The Win32 library functions the exact same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim selectedTimeZone As TimeZones.Win32.Win32TimeZone =
TimeZones.Win32.TimeZones.GetTimeZone(timeZone)
```

In VB.NET you should be using the following class to replace `Win32TimeZone`

[MSDN TimeZone Class (System)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.aspx#Y0)

Refer to the link i provided above to see the correct way of using the TimeZone Class in VB.NET.

It appears to not wont work due to `TimZones.Win32.Win32TimeZone` not being a valid class of .NET

Answer (score 1):

That Timezones library is not a in the .NET BCL.  Contact the author of your Timezones library for help.